# EDB Replication Server - Replicate from EDB Postgres Advanced Server 9.3 to EDB Postgres Advanced Server 9.6

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.6

I am new to EDB Replication Server and I was wondering if I can use this tool to upgrade from EDB Postgres Plus Advanced Server 9.3 to EDB Postgres Plus Advanced Server 9.6.

Is this a bad idea?  What issues might I encounter?